# How to update column with array of values in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have some table in sqlite data base with 12 rows 5 column of values like this http://pastie.org/5170518 . Now i want to update my table for planvalue,YTDOver,YTDVariation column with array of values. How to write query for this update? Can any body help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need your code to tell you more but, the following code should work if you are updating some values.

```
UDATE table_name SET column_name = some_value WHERE condition1 = value1 AND condition2 = value2;
```

If you are adding some new entries then use the INSERT command.

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES(value0, value1, value2, ...);
```